# Small Extra Linking Blocks Beside Anchor Blocks

Tags: html, css

This is very strange. Here's the code:

```
nav {
  position:relative;
}
ul.navul {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  background-color:rgba(12,11,11,0.9);
}
.navul li {
  list-style-type:none;
  display:inline-block;
  border-left:1px solid white;
}
.navul li:first-child {
  border-left:none;
}
.navul a {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  margin:0px;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Here is a snapshot of what I see:

Little Blocks Of Link

[image]

As I decrease the padding in 'a' tag, the size of the blocks go smaller and vice versa. I have already made list-style-type as "none". I have tried making padding:0 and margin:0 on 'li' tag but it doesn't seem to work. I really don't have a clue of what's going on.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I've removed the blue border and instead added the white border around the anchor `a` tags rather than the `li` tags

```
nav {
  position:relative;
}
ul.navul {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  background-color:rgba(12,11,11,0.9);
}
.navul li {
  list-style-type:none;
  display:inline-block;

}
.navul a:first-child {
  border-left:none;
}
.navul a {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px;
  margin:0px;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
  border-left:1px solid white;
}
```

Comment: Actually, I used the blue border intentionally to show the blue linked blocks. What are those blocks?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your image and it only showed the blue border, instead of the little blue boxes. May I ask what environment you're running it on?

Here's the same image, but border in red and +5px margins around `a` tags to increase visibility.
[sample image](http://i.imgur.com/MCXQECO.png)

Comment: Strange. I tried it on Codepen, JSBin, CSSDeck - all showed the same thing.

Comment: Can you please do it on any of the coding platforms and send a link. It would be helpful.